# Run code in scope first after Factory method is finished in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, wait, factory, promise, deferred

So this is my factory code:

```
app.factory('simpleFactory', function ($http) {
   var factory = {}; 

     factory.getArray = function (srchWord) {

         **Here i have a code that uses $http to fill a array called result with values.

           return result;
      };

    return factory;
});
```

And this is the code inside my scope:

```
 $scope.search = function() {

        $scope.arrayValue = simpleFactory.getArray($scope.searchWord);

        $scope.booleanValue = ($scope.arrayValue.length <= 0); // <-- PROBLEM! This gets executed before getArray() is finished.

 };
```

My problem is that `$scope.booleanValue = ($scope.arrayValue.length <= 0)` is executed before `$scope.arrayValue` has gotten its value form  `$simpleFactory.getArray($scope.searchWord)`.
So my question is how I can wait until the getArray function is finished to fire my code:

```
$scope.arrayValue = simpleFactory.getArray($scope.searchWord);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly return a `promise` from the factory method `getArray`.

```
app.factory('simpleFactory', function ($http) {
   var factory = {}; 

     factory.getArray = function (srchWord) {

         return $http.query(....);  // this returns promise;
      };

    return factory;
});
```

Secondly wait for the promise to resolve using then.

```
scope.arrayValue = simpleFactory.getArray($scope.searchWord).then(function(data) {
   $scope.arrayValue=data;
   $scope.booleanValue = ($scope.arrayValue.length <= 0);
});
```

Read about the what `promise` is, how `$http` uses them.

Comment: Thanks, i read about promises, and managed to fix the problem :D

Answer (score 1):

You can either set the boolean value as a callback of the getArray function, or you can set a watch on the arrayValue and update the booleanValue based on that.

```
$scope.search = function() {

    simpleFactory.getArray($scope.searchWord, function(result) {
        $scope.arrayValue = result;
        $scope.booleanValue = ($scope.arrayValue.length <= 0);
    });

    // or

    // initialize the value
    $scope.arrayValue = [];

    // *then* set the value, so it triggers the change on the $watch below    
    $scope.arrayValue = simpleFactory.getArray($scope.searchWord);

    $scope.$watch('arrayValue', function(newValue,oldValue) {
        $scope.booleanValue = (newValue.length <= 0);
    });

 };
```

Comment: i tried the second option, but i always get a empty array, even though arrayValue is not empty... Any ideas?

Comment: it works with oldValue, but then its obiously one step behind all the time :P
For some reason newValue always return an empty array :/